# What is this quotient space for SO(3)?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

What is the quotient space $S^{2}\times S^{2}\times S^{2}/\sim$ topologically amd
geometrically, where $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and the equivalence relation
is defined as $$\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)\sim\left(p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}\right)$$
iff there exists $T\in SO(3)$ (special linear group) such that $$T\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)=\left(p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}\right)?$$
Thanks.

Comment: Don't know much. You can rotate $p_1$ to be the North pole, and then further rotate about the axis connecting the poles, leading roughly to $(S^2\times S^2)/SO(2)$. Generically the stabilizer is trivial, but there are special points when $p_1,p_2,p_3$ sit on the same axis. To my non-expert brain this suggests that may be the quotient is not a manifold?

Comment: Reposting a question is a violation of site rules. Don't do that. Like, never. If you don't get an answer, just wait. The users capable of answering will still see it. By reposting you create garbage, because then the discussion is spread wider, people wasting their time repeating the same points etc.

Comment: @SteveD Just wondering, is $SO(3)$ a duplicate of $O(3)$? Best regards.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Just wondering, is $SO(3)$ the same as $O(3)? Best regards.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There has been no answer received to that different question. Best regards.

Comment: Whether your question gets answered or not is immaterial. It is still bad form to repost. Adding more information to the first version will still "bump" it to the front page. Mind you, if you bump too frequently that is still bad form. You should not try to "hog" attention. The interested people will find it weeks later.

Comment: [An overview of the rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking). See meta for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a rotation sending $p_1,p_2$ to $(1,0,0),(t,\sqrt{1-t^2},0)$ if $p_2\ne \pm p_1$ then $t\ne \pm 1$ and the orbit is fully determined by $t$ and the image of $p_3$

(if $t= \pm 1$ send $p_3$ to $(s,\sqrt{1-s^2},0)$)

In particular $\{ (p_1,p_2,p_3),p_2\ne \pm p_1\} / SO_3\cong (-1,1)\times S^2$

The missing points are $\pm 1\times [-1,1]$.

The topology on $(-1,1)\times S^2$ is obvious, the topology on $(-1,1)\times S^2\cup \pm 1\times [-1,1]$ near one of the extreme point is induced by $|t-t'|+ \|(p_3)_1-s'\|$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is your homeomorphism map and what is the resulting space exactly? Thanks.